# use of definition of limit to prove lim (x->2) x^2-2x+1

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

[image]

I thought  I knew how to solve this kind of problems, but I really don't know how to start...

Comment: You can start by reading solutions of similar problems with [epsilon-delta tag](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/epsilon-delta)

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that if, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that whenever $0<|x-c|<\delta$, it follows that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$,  then $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow c} f(x)=L$.

So for example, on (i), you want $|(x^2-2x+1)-1|<\epsilon$, or $|x||x-2|<\epsilon$.  If you choose delta to be no bigger than $1$, then you can say that $|x|$ will be no bigger than $3$.  So you'd want to choose $\delta=\min(1,\epsilon/3)$.  That way, you have, whenever $0<|x-2|<\delta$, it follows that
$$|x||x-2|<3\delta\le3\frac{\epsilon}{3}$$
$$|x^2-2x|<\epsilon$$
$$|(x^2-2x+1)-1|<\epsilon,$$
as desired.

Comment: I thought L was 2.. now I know how to solve it

Comment: can you solve second question too?

Answer (score 1):

You need to show that for each $ \epsilon >0 $, there exists $\delta >0$ such that if $o<|x-2|<\delta$ then $|(x^{2}-2x+1)-1|=|x^{2}-2x|<\epsilon$.

Let $ \epsilon >0 $ and $|x|<3$.

Observe that $|(x^{2}-2x+1)-1|=|x^{2}-2x|=|x||x-2|<3|x-2|$.

Now choose $\delta =\min\{3,\epsilon/3\}$. Then $\delta>0$.

Suppose $o<|x-2|<\delta$. Then $|x-2|<\epsilon/3$ and we have $|(x^{2}-2x+1)-1|<\epsilon $. 
Therefore $$\lim\limits_{x\to 2}x^{2}-2x+1=1.$$

Comment: how can $x\rightarrow 2$ if $|x|<1$?

Comment: can you solve second problem?

Comment: Hint: $|\sqrt{3x^{2}+4}-2|=\dfrac{|(\sqrt{3x^{2}+4}-2)(\sqrt{3x^{2}+4}+2)|}{|\sqrt{3x^{2}+4}+2|}=\dfrac{3|x|^{2}}{|\sqrt{3x^{2}+4}+2|}$. Now try to find $ \delta >0 $ such that $0<|x|<\delta $ and $\dfrac{3|x|^{2}}{|\sqrt{3x^{2}+4}+2|}<\epsilon $.